# serve http on localhost and open default browser without toolbar

Tags: browser

Is there a crossplatform way to open the default browser without a toolbar and point it to localhost, where my app will serve http?

eg in C++, python, golang or java?

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, you can download the chrome-cli:

```
brew install chrome-cli
chrome-cli open <url>  (Open url in new tab)
chrome-cli open <url> -n  (Open url in new window)
chrome-cli open <url> -i  (Open url in new incognito window)
chrome-cli open <url> -t <id>  (Open url in specific tab)
chrome-cli open <url> -w <id>  (Open url in new tab in specific window)
```

On Linux, you will need xdg-open:

```
sudo apt-get install xdg-open
xdg-open open <url>  (Open url in new tab)
```